# Receive Push Notifications for Web Apps running in a WebView

Tags: android, flutter, web, webview, push-notification

I have implemented a "super app" for Android & iOS that opens various web apps in a WebView, allowing users to access standard services without having to leave the app.

### The Flow

The user opens the Mobile App

The user selects a web app from the list of common apps like Facebook, Twitter, Deliveroo,
Uber, and other shopping, food delivery, and ride-hailing apps.

### The Problem

The web apps work fine for everything, however, the push notifications are not received by the WebView.

### What I have tried

I have tried using Google Chrome Push Notifications for this. However, it only supports Chrome and it is not possible to receive these notifications in iframe or WebView.

### What I Expect

I expect to be able to receive notifications from these web apps of various services I have integrated, as it is not 100% usable if my users are not able to get notifications for these web apps.

Comment: you can use firebase and service.java and firebase-function to call service.java in background, as data enter from webview , coming in database, call notification service file.

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI can you please explain your solution? Also please note that these notifications are coming from a third-party, not our own backend.

Comment: can you give third party name, so answer will make some direction.  @Eric is also giving one third party solution.

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI some web apps we use in WebView are Uber, Deliveroo, and Facebook. Other examples are already specified in the answer.

Comment: Push notifications are not supported in Webview.

Answer (score -1):

Pushy works pretty well. I don't know if your usecase specific does the Job. But may worth a try

[Have a look in Pushy](https://pushy.me/)

Comment: this is also good, is it work if apps is made in webview, i mean with their webview database

Comment: Eric this will work only if we control the backend for the web apps being shown in the WebView. However, this is not the case as specified in the details already. So, this is irrelevant and not something useful for the use case specified.

Answer (score -1):

step 1 )  webview data is saving,i think upto this you are coming.

step 2 )  connect with firebase

step 3 )  create like below FirebaseMessagingService.java, below is just example,

```
    public class FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

      //  showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("notification"));
    //    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        showNotification( remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

    }

    private void showNotification(String Body ,String Title ) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentTitle(Title)
                .setContentText(Body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dd)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }


}
```

step 4) call above FirebaseMessagingService.java in manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

step 5) also create instance id and channel .

step 6) enable cloud messaging and firebase function .

step 7) once firebase function is enabled , it calls in background and you/all will receive notification

try like this way, make some code , if still error , then edit question and add that error here, so we can easily solve this issue. comment if query.

Comment: This will work only for getting notifications from our own Firebase FCM or from our own backend. Unfortunately, this will not catch notifications from other web apps like facebook, Twitter, Uber, etc.

Comment: you have one more solution , 1) send notification using javascript 2) use cron jobs to call file in background, 3) in this case firebase not required but notification service requried

Comment: We are not the ones sending the notifications. The third-party services send the notifications. This is the problem explained here.

Comment: third party service name?

Comment: Please see the answer to the same question you have in the comments of the question.

Comment: from where you want to send notification . you are just giving  Uber, Deliveroo, and Facebook . they are using different technique. which SERVICE you are trying to send notification